# How to get Comments of rss feeds by using rome in java

Tags: java, rss, rome

I am using rome 0.9 for fetching feeds .But i am not able to get the comments of that blog.

```
 InputStream is = new URL(urlstring).openConnection().getInputStream();
        SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
        SyndFeed feed = (SyndFeed) input.build(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        Iterator entries = feed.getEntries().iterator();
            author = entry.getAuthor();
            title = entry.getTitle();
```

i am able to get all parameters but not able to get the comments...

Answer (score 0):

I guess that would be probably a separate feed if available at all. Check the blog if it provides a separate feed for comments and read that in addition to the main feed for posts.